# Error "read would block OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError" when using Koala

Tags: ruby, error-handling, koala-gem

```
"read would block OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError"
```

I'm try to disable verification ssl with code

```
Koala.http_service.http_options = {
  # Faraday options
  :ssl => {
    # see below for info on ca_path and ca_file
    #:ca_file => file,
    #:ca_path => path,
    # SSL verify defaults to true unless you explicitly set it to false
    :verify => false
  }
}
```

but witout success, same error.

How to fix it? And why code above is ignored?